# Как объявить класс с переменной String^ в другом классе?

Tags: массивы, winforms, c++-cli

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые участники форума!
Я работаю в Visual C++ 2008 Express, Windows Forms. 
Имеются 2 класса, вынесенные в отдельный файл line.h. Имеется форма Form1, к которой подключен данный файл.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нужно правильно объявить массив объектов класса **`segment`** в классе **`lines`**. И каким образом потом объявить массив объектов класса **`lines`** в форме.

```
// line.h
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace System;
ref class segment
{
public:
    short s_index;
    short thick;
    String^ time;
};

ref class lines
{
public:
    short l_index;
    String^ name;
    short s_number;
    array<segment^ >^ seg = gcnew array<segment^ >(10);
};
```

Компилятор ругается на строчку:
**`array<segment^ >^ seg = gcnew array<segment^ >(10);`**

> error C3845: lines::seg: только статические данные-члены можно инициализировать внутри класс ссылки или типа, передаваемого по значению

**Заранее спасибо!**

#### Вопрос решен, выражаю бесконечную благодарность [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)

```
// lines.h
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace System;

ref class segment
    {
    public:
        short s_index;
        short thick;
        String^ time;
    };

ref class lines
{
public:
    lines()
    {
        seg = gcnew array<segment^ >(10);
        for(int i=0; i<seg->Length; i++)
        {
            seg[i] = gcnew segment();       
        }
    }

    short l_index;
    String^ name;
    short s_number;
    array<segment^ >^ seg;
};
```

**В Form1:**

```
// Код обработчика события button1_Click в Form1
public: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    array<lines^ >^ line;
    line.l_index = 4;
    array<lines^ >^ line;
    line = gcnew array<lines^ >(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < line->Length; i++)
    {
       line[i] = gcnew lines();       
    }
    line[1]->seg[1]->s_index = 4;
    textBox1->Text = Convert::ToString(line[1]->seg[1]->s_index);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инициализируйте данные в конструкторе.

Ну или переходите на C#, он сделает это за вас автоматически. (C++/CLI — ужасный гибрид, худшее из обоих миров минус выразительность.)

Код:

```
ref class lines
{
public:
    lines()
    {
        seg = gcnew array<segment^ >(10);
    }

    short l_index;
    String^ name;
    short s_number;
    array<segment^ >^ seg;
};
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Можно подробнее? Желательно с кодом.
По поводу C# я с Вами полностью согласен, но дело в том, что я практически уже дописал дипломную работу на C++ (представляете? я пишу диплом и не могу разобраться с такой ерундой, при том, что я без преувеличения лучший в группе). После того как допишу - в планах взяться за C# и переписать работу уже на нем.
Помогите, пожалуйста, уважаемый, разобраться

Comment: @Xandmore: добавил код.

Comment: @VladD: огромное спасибо! Вы - настоящий волшебник!
Класс теперь полностью рабочий. Основываясь на Вашем коде я объявил объекты класса lines в обработчике события button1_Click на Form 1:

array<lines^ >^ line;
line = gcnew array<lines^ >(10);
line[1]->name = gcnew String("Работает");
textBox2->Text = line[1]->name;

Компилируется данный код без ошибок, однако при нажатии button1 в запущенном окне:
Необрабатываемое исключение в приложении->Сведения:

Comment: @VladD:
System.NullReferenceException: В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект.
в Test.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в form1.h:строка 162

То есть ругается на строку:
line[1]->name = gcnew String("Работает");

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно инициализировать объекты массива и получить к ним доступ

Comment: @Xandmore: Смотрите. Вы соадали массив из 10 штук `segment^`, то есть, 10 указателей на `segment`. Какое значение этих указателей? Разумеется, `null`. Вам, по идее, надо заполнить массив. Например, вы можете создать эти все `segment`'ы при помощи `gcnew`, или взять откуда-то и положить в ваш массив.

Comment: @VladD: я бы Вас расцеловал, если мог :)
Все получилось, не знаю, как выложить код, в комментарий не помещается

Comment: @Xandmore: Если вы девушка, то я не против :) В любом случае, очень хорошо, что всё заработало! Удачи вам!